# Ejecutar con Jquery y .Ajax un Modal Bootstrap 3 que está en modal.php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap

El problema es que el modal que tiene que cargar en mi página es muy pesado y si lo añado al item.php se ralentiza mucho la web porque lo carga completamente, aunque no lo use. Además uso varios modals en la página, por lo que si los añado todos la página se hace muy pesada porque los modals tiene muchas imágenes en carrusel.

¿Cómo puedo ejecutar un modal con un .click pero que estando el modal en otro .php para que sólo se cargue si se hace clic?

- Mi botón es algo así:

```
<a id="mostrar" class="btn btn-info active" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#capturacompararModal" href="#">mostrar modal</a>
```

- Y he probado cosas como esta:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#mostrar").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "modal.php",
                    success: function(returndata){
                          // $('#myModal').modal('show');

                             $('#capturacompararModal').html(returndata);
                             $('#capturacompararModal').modal('show');
                    },
                    dataType: "html"
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera, supongamos que tengo 2 archivos `index.php` y `pruebas.php`.

En el archivo `index.php` tengo esto:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
<a id="mostrar" class="btn btn-info active" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#capturacompararModal" href="#">mostrar modal</a>
<div id="mod"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mostrar").click(function () {
            $('#mod').load('pruebas.php', function () {
                $('#elmodal').modal({show: true});
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

En el archivo `pruebas.php` tengo el modal:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="elmodal">
    <div class="show modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Entonces lo único que hice fue que con **jQuery** le indique que si presionaban el botón de **Mostrar Modal** al **div** con `id="mod"` le hiciera un `load()` del archivo `pruebas.php` y dentro del mismo **load** le mando una función para decirle que al modal que estoy cargando y que tiene `id="elmodal"` le haga un `show: true`.

Con eso una vez que presionas el botón de Mostrar modal lo que va a hacer es agregar el código de `pruebas.php` dinamicamente y te mostrara inmediatamente el modal.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, muestra el modal pero con sólo texto, si le añado contenido php no lo muestra.

¿Hay alguna forma de que dentro de <div class="modal-body"> en el modal se pueda añadir php, como por ejemplo: 

<a href="<?php echo osc_search_url(array('sCategory' => osc_item_category_id())); ?>"><?php echo osc_item_category(); ?></a>

Comment: Al cargar php desde el lado del servidor hay que añadir .Ajax en el SCRIPT. ¿Alguna sugerencia para cargar el modal que está en un archivo php en el index.php usando click y ajax?

Comment: Voy formular una nueva pregunta pero pidiendo que se haga con .ajax, ¿esta pregunta cómo la paso a ya resuelta?

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió puedes hacerlo con la palomita verde aun lado de ella y puntuarla hacia arriba.